# Moving PATH to my .bashrc?

Tags: linux

Following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/davps/6c6e0ba59d023a9e3963cea4ad0fb516),

I don't get the last line :

> Don't forget to add the PATH to your .bashrc to make it permanent.

What exactly should I be doing ?

Answer (score 1):

The statement you quoted is about the `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` line from

> For testing add /usr/local/bin to your path
>
> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
> node -v
> npm -v
> ```

The fragment `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` adds the path `/usr/local/bin` to the content of the `PATH` environment variable. This variable is used by the shell (`bash`) to search for executable programs.

The `export` in front of it tells `bash` to forward the updated `PATH` variable to all programs it launches.

Adding the line to `.bashrc` makes it run again every time you start a new `bash` instance (the environment variables are not stored anywhere, their values are set when `bash` starts).

`/usr/local/bin` is a standard path. Most probably you don't have to add that line to `.bashrc` or execute it at all. Use `echo $PATH` to check. If its output already contains `/usr/local/bin` (or contains it twice if you already executed the line above) then you don't need to do anything else. `bash` is able to find `node` and `npm`.

If `/usr/local/bin` is not in the output of `echo $PATH` (or it is only once after you have executed `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` then run:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

to put `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` on a new line at the end of `~/.bashrc`.